# Python, pandas: Cut off filter for spikes in a cumulative series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a cumulative series of values like this:

```
1821, 2015-01-26 22:14:42+02:00, 24574.7 
1822, 2015-01-26 22:15:05+02:00, 24574.7 
1823, 2015-01-26 22:15:28+02:00, 24574.8 
1824, 2015-01-26 22:15:49+02:00, 24574.9 
1825, 2015-01-26 22:16:11+02:00, 24574.9 
1826, 2015-01-26 22:16:34+02:00, 24576.0 
1828, 2015-01-26 22:17:19+02:00, 24575.1 
1829, 2015-01-26 22:17:41+02:00, 24575.2 
1830, 2015-01-26 22:18:03+02:00, 24575.3 
1831, 2015-01-26 22:18:25+02:00, 24575.3
```

The problem is that sometimes I get values that are not normal for a series that is cumulative and values should only increase. Like in line 1826 (value is 24576 and the next one is smaller). Is there a way to remove these values from a Pandas Series object? I.e. when a value is more than the previous and next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in method for this [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff):

```
In [30]:

pd.concat([df.head(1), df[df['cumulative value'].diff()>=0]])
Out[30]:
               timestamp  cumulative value
0                                         
1821 2015-01-26 20:14:42           24574.7
1822 2015-01-26 20:15:05           24574.7
1823 2015-01-26 20:15:28           24574.8
1824 2015-01-26 20:15:49           24574.9
1825 2015-01-26 20:16:11           24574.9
1826 2015-01-26 20:16:34           24576.0
1829 2015-01-26 20:17:41           24575.2
1830 2015-01-26 20:18:03           24575.3
1831 2015-01-26 20:18:25           24575.3
```

**EDIT** 
as pointed out calling `diff` here will lose the first row so I'm using a ugly hack where I concatenate the first row with the result of the `diff` so I don't lose the first row

Comment: Using `diff` like this drops the first row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.diff()` to calculate adjacent differences.  Anywhere the difference is negative you know you need to remove the preceding row.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a one line solution using Pandas' [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). The one-liner also employs some other tricks:  Pandas' `map` and `diff` methods and a `lambda` function. `map` is used to apply the `lambda` function to all rows. The `lambda` function is needed to create a custom less-then comparison that will evaluate NaN values to True.

The following example illustrates.

DISCLAIMER: This only works if we can assume every row is always greater than or equal to the row two positions previous. In other words: row[i] >= row[i-2]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','d','e', 'f', 'g'], 'B': [1,2,2,4,3,5,6]})

# We're going to use Pandas' diff method, telling it to take the difference 1 row back.
print df['B'].diff(1)

# Createa  boolean index. We use map and a lambda function to handle the tricky case of the first row evaluating to 
print df['B'].diff(1).map(lambda x: not(x<0))

# Here is the one line solution!
# Redefine df to only contain the rows that behave themselves.
df = df[df['B'].diff(1).map(lambda x: not(x<0))]

print df
```